# How to deploy Azure Logic App and prerequisite?

Tags: azure

I've built a Logic App on Azure and it's working fine, this app connects to an API and then puts the data into an SQL server.

This app will need to be deployed to another subscription/resource group entirely at some point, I'm just wondering about the recommended methods for this, at the moment I'm attempting to use Azure DevOps to automate this process, and while I can run SQL against databases that are already there, I'm having trouble with deploying the logic app and then linking it to the SQL database previously deployed.

I'm using Power Shell on Azure DevOps as there doesn't seem to individual actions that I can use to deploy a particular resource (such as a Logic App).

Is Azure DevOps the way to go? Am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic app requires connection resources which have the credential information for talking to mail or Azure blob. These have to be created in the target resource group.

You can download the logic app and connections as an ARM template using [Logic app VS tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio).

You can then deploy this [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-logic-apps-with-visual-studio) any other subscription or resource group.

However, OAuth based connections like "mail"  will have to be authenticated manually in the new resource group.